# Why am I suddenly getting a strange compilation error for all Razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Moments ago my MVC Core 2 application was working fine. I have made a few code changes, including to one Razor view, `Explorer.cshtml`. I made some changes to this view while the project was still running, but then restarted the project. I then got the following error:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately. Generated Code
>
> Invalid name for a preprocessing symbol; '' is not a valid identifier

Below that is more detailed technical information:

```
#pragma checksum "C:\Projects\QuickDrive\Code\QuickShare.Web\Views\Account\Login.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "df49f12d3dd65e90ad41ca32ffb37151b1b0bae2"
// <auto-generated/>
#pragma warning disable 1591
[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Account/Login.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Account_Login_cshtml))]
namespace AspNetCore
{
    #line hidden
```

The above error data is for `Login.cshtml`, where it was first for `Explorer.cshtml`. I have not changed `Login.cshtml` for several weeks, but it is the first view that is normally displayed.

It would seem that whatever dynamically compiles Razor views is somehow broken, but if I add a new MVC Core 2 app, it works and the home page renders fine.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution, and even manually deleting the bin and obj folders, then doing a clean and rebuild, to no avail. I have even tried rolling back the project to several commits before this started taking place, but now every time I try an run my project, I still get this error. Whatever could be wrong here?

The only fix for this I can see right now is to create a new, working MVC project and copy everything over from the broken one. This error is surely not caused by something in my code, so copying only the code over, and no hidden faulty artifacts should hopefully work.

Comment: Hi.. i think this happened to me..ages ago though sorry.... Only thing I can think of is to check the value of the "MvcBuildViews" attribute in the main projects file. Set it to true. I think that's what I did..

Comment: Thnnks, @Wheels73, but I've already recreated a new working project. Strangely I can find `MvcBuildViews` in neither project file. Maybe because this is a Core 2 project?

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly the same error. What I had to do, was change my .csproj from:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;Debug;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

The same problem was encountered here. Interestingly, the debug version of the solution had an issue when running thru VS2017, but, the release version was OK. Hopefully, that helps someone - more investigation is required to resolve the issue.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).